# SQL - Calculate average revenue per month using start date

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff, metabase

A bit unfamiliar with this but wondering how I can use a similar function on SQL as this Google Sheets function to pull "average" monthly revenue based on the start_date a product started selling.

```
=iferror(H200DATEDIF(VLOOKUP($A172,'DATA'!$A$2:$H$1000,13, false),TODAY(),"M"),0)
```

on SQL, if I were to want to pull the average monthly revenue from TODAY and by the number of months the product has been released, how would that look instead?

So far, I have:

```
SELECT 
 `product`.`id` AS `id`,
  DATE_FORMAT(`product`.start_selling_date, "%m/%d/%Y") AS `release_day`,
 `product`.`revenue`  as `rev`,
 FROM `product`
```

The goal would be to take the `rev` part which gives me total revenue and divide it by the number of months it's been since the `release_day`.

Example:
Product A launched on 2022-01-21 and has $10,000 in revenue. The average monthly would be around $1,428.57 (7 months). If it's possible to have SQL calculate that automatically when pulling the rest of the information (product ID, release_day, revenue, average monthly revenue)

Is it maybe something like DATEDIFF?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `DATEDIFF()`. Assuming the date field is an actual `date` or `datetime` field, something like...

```
SELECT
product.revenue / ( DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), product.start_selling_date ) / 30 ) AS average_monthly_revenue
```

I am using 30 day months here, but you could get more accurate if needed.